# Can I use the original drain line after I move my washing machine twenty feet away?

Tags: appliances, drain, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

I currently have a washing machine and dryer in the basement and wish to move them both upstairs. I can tap into the same drain line, but it will be about 20' from the old p-trap. Should I install a new p-trap upstairs and take the old one out, or can I have 2 in the same line, or is the one in the basement sufficient?

Also there is no vent in the basement for this drain line just a p-trap and about 3' of pipe sticking up; will I need a vent now that I am moving it upstairs?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should move the P-trap upstairs, and vent through the roof.
Under no circumstances should you have two p-traps in one line.  You get an air-lock between the two, and funny stuff happens.

You want something like this: 
[image]

Comment: Awesome. I'd like to see Google Sketchup do *that*!