# How can I tighten a bolt in a circular hole?

Tags: tools

I've assembled a set of swings, and am trying to tighten the nuts at the top. The trouble is that they are embedded deep inside a circular hole and I can't get to them with a regular spanner.

What kind of tool should I be using? I had a good look in my local hardware store and couldn't see anything useful.

Here's a (dreadful) diagram of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: By my standards, that's an excellent diagram.  See: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/26508/928

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should get yourself a socket wrench (also known as a ratchet):

[image: Socket set]

Comment: Note, no affiliation, but I do like Craftsman tools in this situation. I took a 20 year old wrench like this back because the quick release go stuck in the release position and they replaced it, no questions asked.

Comment: For deep locations, there are deep sockets as well, about 4-5 the length of the ones shown. Craftsman at 1/4 the price of Snap-On, with a lifetime warranty on applicable tools... They will last a lifetime, unlike a lot of the cheap bubblegum wrapper tinfoil and zinc stuff.

Comment: I didn't see one of these in the hardware store, but I did see a "Torque Wrench". Is that the same?

Comment: @Urbycoz A torque wrench is a more specialized tool. There are pages of results when I search on "socket wrench" at my local hardware store. You can also try searching on ratchet set and mechanics tool set.

Comment: @Urbycoz: every respectable hardware store will sell socket wrench kits. Ask a staff guy for ratchets and sockets and he'll be able to direct you.

Comment: @Urbycoz - If you do not have a "respectable hardware store" in your area then try at an automotive parts store. They sell plenty of socket wrenches.

Comment: @BMitch The only time I've every collected on the Craftsman guarantee was with a 23 mm socket that I broke trying to remove the Jesus nut from an old Toyota engine (the break revealed a minor casting flaw). The guy at the desk boggled at it for a while and fetched another one and only once he'd handed it over did he ask how we'd done it.

Answer (score 14):

You want a nut driver.  You can either get a fixed set of them,

[image: Nut driver set]

or if you have a socket set, you can just get a nut driver with a square head that you clip the sockets onto:

[image: Nut driver for sockets]

Or you could get a set of these, a power drill, and the socket, and use that to get it really tight.  If you're going to tighten stuff instead of drill holes with a power drill, I recommend you read our [blog post](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/clutches-torque-and-you/) on the proper use of the clutch on a power drill.

[image: Power bar set for drills]

Comment: If you're spinning the nuts with a drill can you safely use the chromed sockets sold with hand tools; or do you need to use the black type rated for use with impact wrenches.

Comment: @DanNeely Unless it's a hammer drill, the chromed sockets should be fine.